# Is it possible to find the visitor email address if the visitor's allow the cookies?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

a) Say I have a potential client - John Smith at XYZ Company;

b) I know their email address and have it in my database - so john@xyz-company.com;

c) But they have never signed into my site or given me their email - so I have the email address from other sources

d) If they have accepted my cookies, will I be able to know when they come to my site (even if they have never registered before)??

Comment: If you've send a cookie to their, then yes, you can detect that cookie is send with a request. But the cookie is not related to the visitor's email address.

Comment: You would need some way to read the cookie and get the info to figure out it was them or track the cookie to know it was them.

Comment: Is it possible by using third-party cookies? Suppose we integrate the chunk of code of Facebook in our website like like button, Can I get the email from cookies? I guess It would definitely be in encrypted form?